# Returning multiple cells from JSON

Tags: json, google-sheets

```
 function CryptoOverview(cryptoID, unused_param) {
//variables here

  var results = new Array(3);
  var data = new Array(3);
  data[0] = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).data.overview;
  data[1] = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).data.background;
  data[2] = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).data.technology;
  results[0] = info;
  return results;

}
```

The code is properly returning the fields but I'm getting an error:

> "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data".

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the code to:

```
function CryptoOverview(cryptoID, unused_param) {
//variables here

//removed the number inside the Array()
  var results = new Array();
  var data = new Array();

 //other

}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you delete all the data in a range where you want to deploy the data from the JSON. you are getting that error clearly because it attempts to populate cells which are not empty - and that's not possible.